# How to implement multi-selection picker using Card Service in Google Drive Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

Have implemented the text box input with suggestion parameters but once an option is selected, the suggestions do not appear again for more options to select.

```
var textInputStyle = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("StyleSelection")
    .setTitle("Style/Nature")
    .setMultiline(true);

var sheetValue = basicSheet.getRange(2,1,basicSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
var Suggestions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sheetValue.length; i++) {
    Suggestions.push(sheetValue[i][0]);
}
textInputStyle.setSuggestions(CardService.newSuggestions().addSuggestions(Suggestions));
```

Comment: Could you share more information on the script and the issue?